# .sql file in docker-entrypoint-initdb not being run

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I am using docker-compose 3.7 to run Postgresql but I can't get my init.sql to run through the docker-entrypoint-initdb.d entry point.

I understand that the volume directory on my machine needs to be empty but I am sure that I am doing that correctly. I must be missing something fairly simple/obvious.

```
version: '3.7'

services:

  postgresdb:
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: appdb
      POSTGRES_USER: appdb 
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ########
    image: bitnami/postgresql:latest
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
    - ./db/postgres_volume:/bitnami:rw
    - ./db/init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql
    restart: always
```

```sql
CREATE TABLE user (
        id SERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
        name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
);
```

My volume directory is empty.

```
$ ls db/postgres_volume/
$
```

The container starts with no issues but from the logs, I can't tell if the init.sql script was executed. Scripts seemed to be loaded but I am not sure about execution.

```
$ docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml up -d postgresdb 
Creating network "app_default" with the default driver
Creating app_postgresdb_1 ... done
$
```

```
postgresdb_1  | INFO  ==> Loading custom scripts...
postgresdb_1  | INFO  ==> Loading user's custom files from /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d ...
postgresdb_1  | INFO  ==> Starting PostgreSQL in background...
```

Logging into the container and then into my database, I see no tables.

```
$ docker exec -it 737845344cf2 bash
I have no name!@737845344cf2:/$ psql -U appdb appdb
appdb=> \dt
Did not find any relations.
```

After the container is created, I see a "postgresql" folder db/postgres_volume but is has no contents.

```
$ ls db/postgres_volume/
postgresql

$ ls db/postgres_volume/postgresql/
$
```

Comment: Can you check the owner and permission of /db/postgres_volume/. It might be a issue. check if the container persists after running , `docker ps`. Also don't use `restart: always`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing, It will never create a table because you are using **reserve word** `user` in table creation. change the user to `"user"`

```
CREATE TABLE "user"(
   user_id serial PRIMARY KEY,
   username VARCHAR (50) UNIQUE NOT NULL
)
```

Second thing, The above will work fine with initialization the DB but there is a mounting [issue](https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-postgresql/issues/102) in the lastest image that might be the reason that the mount directory seemed empty.

Also in the documentation, the path is `-v /path/to/postgresql-persistence:/bitnami/postgresql` [Persisting your database](https://hub.docker.com/r/bitnami/postgresql/)

[image]